# titanium mobile　で Cannot find module 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\alloy.cmd'

Tags: android, windows-8

titanium mobileで開発しています。
android版で、環境はwindows8.1です。

パブリッシュの際に、titanium SDKのバージョンを変えたのですが、
それが原因なのか、以下のようなエラーが出てビルドできなくなりました。
ほかのプロジェクトをビルドしても同様なエラーが出るようになりました。

> [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process 
>   exit value was 1 
>   [ERROR] :  : Cannot find module 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\alloy.cmd'
>   [ERROR] :  Alloy compiler failed

対処として、

・プロジェクトを一度削除して再インポート
・titanium studio をアンインストールして再インストール
・本来alloy.cmdが置かれていた場所にpathを通してみた
・C:\WINDOWS\system32\ に ドライブ内を検索して見つけたalloy.cmdを置く

等をしましたが、状況変わらず。

どなたか対処を知っていましたら教えていただけないでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。